# Installing CentOS packages on fedora from repository

Tags: centos, yum, fedora, package-management, dnf

Is there a way to install CentOS packages on Fedora through yum (dnf) repository? I'm trying to install freeswitch, but their own repository only provides builds for RHEL and CentOS. I assume CentOS and Fedora are compatible enough to install rpm package, but it would be nicer if I could use repository.

Below is the repository query from CentOS machine.

```
[foverzar@localhost ~]$ yum list freeswitch
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.logol.ru
 * epel: fedora-mirror01.rbc.ru
 * extras: mirror.logol.ru
 * updates: mirror.h1host.ru
Installed Packages
freeswitch.x86_64                   1.6.13-1.el7.centos                   @freeswitch
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't count on it.

While CentOS is a clone of RHEL, which is forked from Fedora every few years, Fedora moves relatively quickly and downstream packages should *not* be considered compatible with upstream, especially after several releases.

This package will probably fail to install, and even if it installs, it will probably fail to run, and even if it runs, it will probably exhibit strange behavior which can't be traced to any obvious cause.

Instead, install FreeSWITCH from source, or rebuild its source RPM on Fedora. (Of course, if you actually try that, you'll find that it fails to build, which should tell you something... I know because I actually tried this and was forced to give up.)

Now after you've done all this experimentation, just go back and install FreeSWITCH on CentOS 7. You'll be happier and more stable.

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions:

- Build FreeSWITCH from source;
- Create rpm package for fedora;
- Install centos distribution in chroot into fedora and install FreeSWITCH rpm package in this centos environment;
- Use docker.